# How did Reda survive for over 9 centuries without apparently aging?

Tags: assassins-creed

Reda met Bayek of Siwa in 48 BCE. He met the viking Eivor sometime in the 9th century, and did not appear to have aged a day. How did he do this?

Comment: Seems to be unexplained so far but I haven't played AC:V myself to know if there is any info in it.

Comment: I've often wondered the same thing about Prince Valiant.